# Importing tables into plsql developer (other than .csv format)

Tags: csv, import, plsql, xlsx, plsqldeveloper

My plan was to export tables from MS Access database to .xlsx
Then convert it to .csv

Then import it into plsql developer.

But .xlsx has a date&time column (07-08-2012 13:01:33) and
when I convert it to .csv, .csv only shows 07-08-2012 .

So my question is... is there any other way to import tables to plsql developer?

Answer (score 1):

Why not export it directly to CSV format, using the Export to Text File option?  Set the file type (when you specify the file name) as CSV. Then the wizard lets you define the export format as delimited, then it defaults to the comma delimiter.

Personally **I always use tab-separated files** when importing to PL/SQL Developer, to avoid conflicts if my data happens to have embedded commas.  You can do that directly from w/in Access 2010 as well, just by follow the steps I gave above while changing the delimiter and the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

From MS Access database, I exported with .txt then converted .csv
Then it contained full date strings.